# Proxy error: Could nor proxy request (ENOTFOUND)

Tags: node.js, proxy, vue-cli

When I run **npm run serve** and make a request I see

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/task from localhost:8080 to http://mevn-api:3080.
> See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ENOTFOUND).

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGlOO.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to run a full-stack app using VUE and ExpressJS. I've placed Front-End part on localhost:8080 and Back-End on localhost:3080. When I make a request I see the error. Please, take a look and the screenshot as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized what was wrong. I typed wrong **target** in **vue.config.js** file.

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            "^/api": {
                target: "localhost:3080",
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "/" after the portnumber.

It should be like http://localhost:5000/

Comment: I am trying to run a full-stack app using VUE and ExpressJS. I've placed Front-End part on localhost:8080 and Back-End on localhost:3080. When I make a request I see the error. Please, take a look and the screenshot as well.

Comment: I've realized what was wrong. I typed wrong target in vue.config.js file.

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            "^/api": {
                target: "localhost:3080",
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
        },
    },
};